# async await is not working in react-native

Tags: javascript, async-await

```js
     first() {
        setTimeout(() => console.log('I am First CALL afer 1 second'), 1000)
      }
      second() {
          console.log("SEcond methof is called");
      }
  
      async  getMoviesFromApi() {
        try {
          let response = await this.first() ;
    
          let response2 =  this.second() ;

        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }
```

Here second function should be called after function first and first will print after 1 second but second is called directly , it is not waiting for function first.
please help

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning a Promise, you are just calling a setTimeout that's not an awaitable

You should do something like this:

```
first() {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
              console.log('I amFirest CAll afer 1 second');
              resolve();
        }, 1000)
   });
}
```

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await